# GET images from div class

Tags: php, html, class, nginx, wget

I'm trying to download a full library of photos from my university housing system.

The system runs on nginx, file parsing for that particular directory is unavailable, 404 returns all the time.

Anyway, every single photo is stored in a **/res/up/250x300** directory, with a number, gender indicator and a random(?) hash, example here;

> 114057-f-95830a765f22b71ad5691adfdec6bfzfc222bb1c7.jpg

There's catalog of users which when called with specific user id returns file in EXACT same format as provided above, and is always stored in:

```
<div class="uwb-imgcover-photo-wrapper"/>
```

So, summarizing, it looks like this.

1. Calling for a specific user;

> /kontroler.php?_action=katalog2/osoby/pokazOsobe&os_id=114057

2. class **uwb-imgcover-photo-wrapper** gives me a link to the photo:

> /res/up/250x300/114057-f-95830a765f22b71ad5691adfdec6bfzfc222bb1c7.jpg

Wget magic doesn't work.

I was thinking about a loop or something like this. This is actually very first time I'm doing anything related to web file catching.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for($i=114050;$i<=114057;$i++){

    $result = file_get_contents('http://domain.com/kontroler.php?_action=katalog2/osoby/pokazOsobe&os_id='.$i);
    if($result){
        preg_match('/\/res\/up\/250x300\/(.*?)\.jpg/',$result,$match);
        if($match){
            $filename = $match[1].'.jpg';
            $imageURL = 'http://domain.com/res/up/250x300/'.$filename;
            $image = file_get_contents($url);

            file_put_contents($filename, $image);
        }
    }

}
```